# Insert string before a certain word within another string

Tags: php, mysql

I'm combining my MySQL queries so the user can select multiple dropdowns and filter based on those dropdowns. This works as intended as I've checked using $echo query. However, I need to insert an "AND " before each occurence of the word "WHERE" except for the first one. At the moment my query comes out like this if I select multiple drodowns:

```
SELECT a.MembershipID,
       a.FirstName,
       a.Surname,
       t.RaceID,
       t.Time,
       r.RaceID,
       r.RaceName,
       r.Distance,
       r.ClubYear
FROM Athlete AS a
INNER JOIN Time AS t ON a.MembershipID=t.MembershipID
INNER JOIN Race AS r ON t.RaceID=r.RaceID
WHERE r.RaceName= 'Parkrun' WHERE r.Distance= '5 kilometres'
ORDER BY a.Surname
```

As you can see on line 4, there are two WHERE queries with no AND. How can I insert an AND before the second WHERE? How can I do this for every subsequent WHERE except the first? I thought about using explode to create substrings, insert the AND and then join them back together, but this seems a little over the top. Any help?
Thanks.

Edit: Add PHP code that generates the above:

```
$query = "SELECT a.MembershipID, a.FirstName, a.Surname, t.RaceID, t.Time, r.RaceID, r.RaceName, r.Distance, r.ClubYear
                            FROM Athlete AS a 
                            INNER JOIN Time AS t  
                                ON a.MembershipID=t.MembershipID
                            INNER JOIN Race AS r
                                ON t.RaceID=r.RaceID";
            if ($_POST['raceName']!= null) {
                $raceName = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["raceName"]);
                $filter = " WHERE r.RaceName= '$raceName'";
                $query .= $filter;
            } 
            if ($_POST['athlete']!= null) {
                $athlete = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["athlete"]);
                $firstWord = explode(' ',trim($athlete));
                $firstName = $firstWord[0];
                $lastWord = explode(' ', $athlete);
                $surname = array_pop($lastWord);
                $filter = " WHERE a.FirstName= '$firstName' AND a.Surname = '$surname'";
                $query .= $filter;
            } 
            if ($_POST['distance']!= null) {
                $distance = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["distance"]);
                $filter = " WHERE r.Distance= '$distance'";
                $query .= $filter;
            } 
            if ($_POST['clubYear']!= null) {
                $clubYear = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["clubYear"]);
                $filter = " WHERE r.ClubYear= '$clubYear'";
                $query .= $filter;
            }

            $fullquery = $query . " ORDER BY a.Surname";
```

Comment: Please give the PHP code that generates this query since the problem is there. You'll also need to replace the second `WHERE` with `AND` and not append the `END` before it, as that would create an `AND WHERE` which is not valid

Comment: Added the PHP that generates it. And also good point, forgot about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to first add an always true statement like `1=1` so you don't have to check if it's the first statement or not, and then keep building you query by appending `AND CONDITION_N` accordingly

```
$query = "SELECT a.MembershipID, a.FirstName, a.Surname, t.RaceID, t.Time, r.RaceID, r.RaceName, r.Distance, r.ClubYear
                            FROM Athlete AS a 
                            INNER JOIN Time AS t  
                                ON a.MembershipID=t.MembershipID
                            INNER JOIN Race AS r
                                ON t.RaceID=r.RaceID";

$query .= " WHERE 1 = 1 ";
if ($_POST['raceName']!= null) {
    $raceName = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["raceName"]);
    $filter = " AND r.RaceName= '$raceName'";
    $query .= $filter;
}
```

**Explanation:**

1. If none or your `if` conditions are true, your query would be whatever your initial query was followed `WHERE 1=1` which is exactly the same as not having it in the first place
2. If any of your conditions are `true` then it would be:

   > `INITIAL_QUERY WHERE 1=1 AND CONDITION_N`
3. For multiple conditions being true it would be:

   > `INITIAL_QUERY WHERE 1=1 AND CONDITION_N AND CONDITION_N+1`

This makes you PHP code cleaner and faster since you don't have to check about whether it is the first condition in order to decide whether to use `WHERE` or `AND` when appending to your select statement

Comment: How does this work for the first statement though? Where does the initial WHERE get added?

Comment: Updated the answer with an explanation for this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make something like

```
WHERE id > 0
```

before the

```
WHERE r.RaceName= 'Parkrun' WHERE r.Distance= '5 kilometres'
```

you'll have something like

```
WHERE id > 0 AND r.RaceName= 'Parkrun' AND r.Distance= '5 kilometres'
```